# favicon.ico присваивается в переменную Flask

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask, url

Есть такая функция роутинга

```
@app.route('/<string:tpaIndex>')
      def mainView(tpaIndex):
         return render_template('index.html',tpaIndex=tpaIndex)
```

И каким-то образом в переменную `tpaIndex`, к которому должно присваиваться значение введенное в адресную строку, влезает строка `favicon.ico` и происходит это после обработки `GET` запроса сервером `[05/May/2022 08:32:22] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -`
Как с этим бороться? Почему-то раньше такой проблемы не было, она возникла из неоткуда

Comment: Потому что браузер самостоятельно пытается найти фавиконку по этому адресу. Это отдельный запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно из за этого:

```
'/<string:tpaIndex>'
```

Под это выражение подходит всё что угодно. Подумайте лучше над роутами.

Как вариант, можете использовать query params:

```
www.example.com/search?name=John&location=Miami
    @app.route('/search', methods=['GET'])
    def search():
        args = request.args
        print(args.get("name"))
```

Comment: Да, решил эту проблему похожим образом